# application builder in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

Can some one guide me where I can find this in Oracle Apex?

1. Navigate to the Page Definition for page one of the application
2. Click the create (+)icon in the Regions section
3. Select HTML for the region type and click Next >
4. Select HTML from the region container list and click Next >
5. Enter (title name) in the Title field
6. Choose Form Region from the Region Template list and click create

I just can not find the create icon in region section.

I tried in oracle apex and I didn’t find the section.

Comment: What version of Oracle APEX are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to create a region is to **right-click** the "Body" (under "Components" in page's rendering section) and then select "Create region":

[image]